# Installing cplexAPI with newest version of cplex 12.10.0 - new error

Tags: r, package, cplex

I want to install the cplexAPI R package to interact with the newest version of IBM CPLEX solver (IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimizers 12.10.0) but I keep getting the following error:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
** package 'cplexAPI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/Users/USERNAME/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\include"         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1214:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:41: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cplex.h:1214:1: note: in expansion of macro 'CPXDEPRECATEDAPI'
 CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(12090000)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:251:62: error: expected ')' before 'deprecated'
 #      define CPXDEPRECATEDAPI(version) __declspec(dllimport deprecated)
```

I have done the following:

1. Installed Rtools40 from [https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/][1], and added `PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"` in my `.Renviron` file
2. Installed IBM CPLEX in `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210`
3. Added the following paths in my `.Renviron` file:

   CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR = "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210"

   CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB = "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\lib"
4. Run `install.packages('cplexAPI')`. I have also tried to manually download the tar.gz file and modify the path in the Makevars.win file, but I get the same error.
   FYI, I have the following R version:

> ```
> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
> arch           x86_64                      
> os             mingw32                     
> system         x86_64, mingw32             
> status                                     
> major          4                           
> minor          0.3                         
> year           2020                        
> month          10                          
> day            10                          
> svn rev        79318                       
> language       R                           
> version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
> nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the cplex library. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199818/318752

A workaround is to add `-DBUILD_CPXSTATIC` to the `PKG_CPPFLAGS` inside the package `src/Makevars.win` as shown here: https://github.com/r-windows/Rcplex/commit/545254ab7cf28e97e62063c16af711ff2b46476d.

I also had to update the dll name because the cplex dll is called `cplex12100.dll` while the R package was still assuming `cplex1263.dll`. With these fixes I am able to install the package on Windows:

```r
install.packages("slam")
install.packages('https://github.com/r-windows/Rcplex/archive/master.tar.gz', repos = NULL, INSTALL_opts = '--no-multiarch')
```