# How to run CPLEX with R language?

Tags: r, gcc, mingw, cplex

I wrote an optimization problem with R language, and want to solve it with CPLEX (I already download cplex1263).
In CRAN, there is a package named **"Rcplex"**, but it doesn't provide the r-release version (see., https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/index.html). If I run "install.packages("Rcplex")", it turns an error back like **"*Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rcplex’*"**.

Besides, I found another package named **"cplexAPI"**, however, when I install this package, I meet a warning which says that "package ‘*cplexAPI’ is not available for this version of R*".
My Windows system is WIN10 and my R version is 4.2.2. I have no idea how to install the cplex interface in R.

---

Following MrFlick's advice, I have done the following things:

1. Update my R version to 4.2.3 and install Rtools 4.3 rom [https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvBIE.png), and added `PATH="${RTOOLS43_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"`, `CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR` and `CPLEX_STUDIO_LIB` to my `.Renviron` file
2. Installed IBM CPLEX in `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210`
3. Download **Rcplex_0.3-6.tar.gz** from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/index.html and follow the guidance in CRAN.

- Unzip **Rcplex_0.3-6.tar.gz**
- Modify the path in `src/Makevars.win`
- Repackage **Rcplex_0.3-6.tar.gz** with `R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual --md5`
- Check the new package with `R CMD check Rcplex`

But when I check this new package, 1 error occurs:

[R CMD check Rcplex_0.3-6.tar.gz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvBIE.png)

```
Check Error: 
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>R CMD check Rcplex
* using log directory 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rcplex.Rcheck'
* using R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file 'Rcplex/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* this is package 'Rcplex' version '0.3-6'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* **checking whether package 'Rcplex' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.**
See 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rcplex.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR
See
  'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Rcplex.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.
```

[error: size of array 'CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST1' is negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cIbf.png)

```
* installing *source* package 'Rcplex' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
"D:/software/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/"gcc  -I"D:/software/R-4.2.3/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"D:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include" -DBUILD_CPXSTATIC    -I"D:/software/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Rcplex.c -o Rcplex.o
In file included from D:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include/ilcplex/cplex.h:17,
                 from Rcplex.h:4,
                 from Rcplex.c:2:
D:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include/ilcplex/cpxconst.h:189:13: error: size of array 'CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST1' is negative
  189 | typedef int CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST1[1 + (int)sizeof(CPXSIZE) - (int)sizeof(size_t)];
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [D:/software/R-4.2.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:255: Rcplex.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcplex'
* removing 'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Rcplex.Rcheck/Rcplex'
```

[Line189 in cpxconst.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFQif.png)

```
/* Make sure that CPXSIZE is exactly as wide as size_t. The test
 * below is a compile time test that works unless sizeof(CPXSIZE)
 * and sizeof(size_t) differ by exactly 1. If the sizes differ by
 * more than 1 then at least one of the typedefs below defines an
 * array of negative length. This should be caught by the compiler.
 */
#ifndef CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST_DISABLE
typedef int CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST1[1 + (int)sizeof(CPXSIZE) - (int)sizeof(size_t)];
typedef int CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST2[1 + (int)sizeof(size_t) - (int)sizeof(CPXSIZE)];
#endif /* !CPXSIZE_BITS_TEST_DISABLE */

#endif /* !CPX_INTWIDTH_H */
```

---

Followed by this question ([External header file ilcplex\cpxconst.h causing causing compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182200/external-header-file-ilcplex-cpxconst-h-causing-causing-compiler-error/61199818#61199818)), it seems to be a compile problem. But I'm not familiar with compilation issues,
I am using CPLEX version 12.6.3, compiling with MinGW, and my operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: The [cplexAPI was removed from CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cplexAPI) because it was not updated to work with newer versions of R/. If you want to try to install `Rcplex` you'll need to install [Rtools 4.2](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html) (to match your version of R). That should provide you with a complier necessary for building the package.

Answer (score 0):

Aside Rcplex you can also use call OPL from R.

1. Through [doopl](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/doopl-R-sample)
2. Calling [oplrun from R with an external call](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/call-opl-cplex-from-r)

diet.r

```
system("oplrun diet.mod diet.dat")
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seems that I need to install Python to use them.  I will try it later~

Comment: With option 2 you do not.