# ilcplex/ilocplex.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cplex

I am a CPLEX newbie trying to use CPLEX in C++. I have linked both cplex library paths to my VS code. These are the CPLEX paths that I added to my C/C++ configuration menu:

C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\cplex\include
C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\concert\include

However, I am still getting the following error:

> ilcplex/ilocplex.h: No such file or directory

error message from VS code:
[image: error message from VS code]

It seems that I have linked the libraries to VS code:

[image: cplex libraries are linked]

Operating system: Windows 10 64 bit
VS Code version: 1.56.0 x64
CPLEX version: 20.1 64 bit
Compiler: Mingw-w64

Comment: I have looked in one of my Cplex projects. I noticed that i added two included dictories CPLEX/concert/include and CPLEX/cplex/include. Are you sure, that Mingw-w64 is supported. As far as i know this compiler is not supported by IBM. You have to use your MS Compiler.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021096/c-cplex-cp-optimizer-makefile-issues-on-project-build-using-clion-with-mingw/73979571#73979571

Answer (score 1):

The use of the Cplex API is well documented.
You have to add two include directories:

C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\cplex\include

C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\concert\include

Moreover, you have to link three libraries (Windows64, VS 2017, Release):

"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\concert\lib\x64_windows_msvc14\stat_mda\concert.lib"

"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\cplex\lib\x64_windows_msvc14\stat_mda\cplex2010.lib"

"C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community201\cplex\lib\x64_windows_msvc14\stat_mda\ilocplex.lib"

Perhaps you will need a precompiler statement:

_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

As far as I know, the **Mingw-64w compiler is not supported** by IBM. You will need the MSVC compiler